# How do I remove the "Tear off this menu" items in gVim?

Tags: vim

How do I remove the "Tear off this menu" items in gVim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute this or add it to your ~/.vimrc or ~/_vimrc:

```
set guioptions-=t
```

See

```
:help guioptions
```